# gt table in Jupyter?

Tags: jupyter-lab, gt

I'm attempting to produce reasonable visual tables in R using JupyterLab without success.

Specifically, I'd like this code chunk, which works beautifully in RStudio, to work in Jupyter:

```
library(gt)
library(gtExtras)
head(mtcars) %>%
     gt() %>% 
     gt_theme_538()
```

In Jupyter this produces a list of 17 table elements, not a formatted table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first save it as an object. This should do it:

```
gts <- function(gt_table){
   gt:::as.tags.gt_tbl(gt_table)
}
```

Then you display your table by calling gts at the end.

```
tbl <- gt(table) %>% ...
     %>% gts
```

Comment: Saving to object, then sending to gts worked:

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!
Saving to an object that is passed to `gts` worked:

```
thing <- head(mtcars) %>%
     gt() %>% 
     gt_theme_538()

thing %>% gts
```